# Split pandas dataframe sentence, by text between ()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Index| Labels  -----------------------------------------|Text       
1.   |[(Task, add), (Application, MAMP) (Task, delete)] |   "add or delete" 
2.   |[(Servername, abhs)]                              |   "servername create"
```

Is it possible to split it in this:

```
Index | Task      | Application | Servername |Text 
1.    |add, delete|MAMP         |            |"add or delete"
2.    |           |             | abhs       |"servername create"
```

Basically Labels is a list with multiple tuple. The first entry of the tuple is the key while the second entry is the value. I want the key as the column name and the value as the value of this row. In case there is another value with the same key they should be added together.

Other columns should be empty if no key is in the row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Index"] = ["1.","2."]
df["Labels"] =[[("Task","add"),("Application", "MAMP"), ("Task", "delete")],[("Servername", "abhs")]]
df["Text"] = ["add or delete", "servername create"]
```

At the moment I'm looking for `")"` and `split` but I think that shouldn't be that complicated and there has to be another way then use them as Strings. 
But I think there is a better way.

Comment: It would be much easier to group by the first value in the tuplie before building the data. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: From Spacy  NER,  named  entities  from model.  ```df['labels'] = df['outcome'].apply(lambda x: _ner_apply(x)) ```   will gave all the labels + label  text

Comment: @Wiktor can you give an explanation why it's closed? Because it's quite clear what he wants and I disagree with the closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Index"] = ["1.","2."]
df["Labels"] =[[("Task","add"),("Application", "MAMP"), ("Task", "delete")],[("Servername", "abhs")]]
df["Text"] = ["add or delete", "servername create"]


def get_labels(labels):
    label_dict = {}
    for label, value in labels:
        label_dict[label] = label_dict.get(label,[]) + [value]
    for key in label_dict:
        label_dict[key] = ", ".join(label_dict[key])  # in case you want it as string and not as list
    return label_dict

df = df.merge(df["Labels"].apply(lambda s: pd.Series(get_labels(s))),
    left_index=True, right_index=True).drop(["Labels"],axis=1).fillna('')

print(df)
```

## Output:

```
  Index               Text Application Servername         Task
0    1.      add or delete        MAMP             add, delete
1    2.  servername create                   abhs
```

As mention in the comment you don't need the second for loop if you would delete it then the output would look like this (what I think is better for future use but that is up to you):

```
  Index               Text           Task Application Servername
0    1.      add or delete  [add, delete]      [MAMP]           
1    2.  servername create                                [abhs]
```